# NPCs don't appear

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

So far, I've built a few houses and they all followed the requirements:

- House must be at least 6 blocks high
- House must be at least 10 blocks wide
- House must have a wall that covers the background
- House must have a chair and a table
- House must have a light source, such as a torch
- House must be far from corruption

So far the only NPC living in an occupited house is the guide, no one else is moving in. All my money is in a chest (as it says if you store your money you won't lose them if you get killed, also I'm on normal difficulty). But should I have my money in my inventory in order for an NPC to appear so I can assign them to one of my built houses? Is there something else I'm missing? I checked housing and it said it's suitable.

**UPDATE:** I have a table too. So that won't work.

**UPDATE 2:** I made the floor stone, since it said a solid floor. But the linked question said to have a wood floor, so I'll change that.

**UPDATE 3:** I have a few hundred coins in my chest, so I won't be able to fit all of them on my inventory, but I'll fit some.

**UPDATE 4:** After a mining trip, I got a message saying a merchant NPC has arrived.

Comment: I am not sure about console, hence why this is a comment, but when you press ESC on the right side, do you have something called "House Query" with a "?" mark? You can use that to check if the house is suitable to be inhabited.

Comment: You need to have at least 50 silver in your inventory in order for the merchant to spawn - having your money in chests doesn't trigger his spawn. Other NPCs have other spawn conditions.

Comment: @Mano I'm on Xbox.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering if the feature was available there too, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, it seems you're missing a Table.

Help with the house, if needed further can be found **[Here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House)**

You also need some requirement to get the individual NPC's so you may need to achieve those.

A list of requirements to get NPC's can be found **[Here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC)**

---

Edit: From your update about coins, yes. you need the required amount of coins (50 silver) on your character in order to attract the assigned NPC - The Merchant.

> You say you have a few hundred coins in your chest. Coins, when in your chests, not your inventory or assigned money pouch do not stack properly.
>
> If you simply pull them out of the chest **Drop them on the ground** somewhere safe away from danger, then pick them back up. they will stack into their respective tiers.

- Copper x 100 will become Silver x 1
- Silver x 100 will become Gold x 1
- Gold x 100 will become Platinum x 1

The 'linked' question said you need a wooden floor, that isn't true. You can have any number of different materials to build your house with, provided they fit within the criteria of building a house. If it were just wood that you were allowed to build with, there would be a lack of aesthetic and diversity to houses, so I can tell you just from that (As well as the fact that I built a home out of stone myself at one point) that **wood isn't your only option.**

Comment: I did add a table.